# Can I use I2C bus or GPIOs as I2C to connect I2C devices?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, gpio

This question is regarding use of I2C Bus/GPIOs as I2C.

My application processor has three I2C controllers. Is it preferable to connect all I2C devices (obviously we can not connect more than 128 devices on I2C) on these buses?

Or, is it preferable to use GPIOs as I2C? (My application processor also has GPIO lines which I can use for I2C purposes.)

When is it preferable to use I2C controllers and when it is preferable to use GPIO lines for I2C interfacing?

Comment: What "application processor" are you using?

Comment: Before running into 128 device limitation you may be limited by the bus capacitance.

Answer (score 4):

Depending how much data is going along the bus, and if there are "conflicts" of device ID's, or data being transferred at the same time, it's no problem to hang all your devices on one bus. That's what I2C was designed for.

To spread the load, using 2 or 3 I2C buses can make things easier (EG keep different systems separate) but it can mean you have to do the same thing 3 times in software. You may do something like use one bus for "high speed" transfer of lots of data (EG to/from a storage device) and another bus running a lot slower to do less critical activities like read a temperature sensor every second or turn an LED on/off.

Bit-banging I2C using GPIO pins is a "last-resort" as it's usually much easier to use the built-in I2C device, and most processors have things like interrupt handlers and DMA to make the work much easier, automate the transfers, save processor load / software overhead, etc.

It's much nicer to have communications handled by interrupts rather than trying to do it by GPIO + waits/timers etc., especially if you have a lot to do / a lot of data to move.

*Edited to add:* It can also be handy to use one bus for devices which need a level shifter (EG 5v devices interfaced to 3.3v micro on one bus, 3.3v native devices on the other bus)

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing an I2C master for a single-master system, I would suggest that bit-banging may be preferable to trying to use built-in hardware.  Among other things:

1. If any devices on the I2C bus get "confused", it can sometimes be difficult to convince hardware master implementations to generate the best waveforms to get them "unstuck" (recommended approach: if SDA isn't floating, or if your device is driving SCK low, assert SDA, assert CLK, release SDA, release CLK, and wait for CLK to go high; repeat as needed, and then assert and release SDA with SCK high).  Note that if an EEPROM device thought it was in the middle of a write cycle, this waveform will cause it to abort the write in progress; if the processor doesn't know why the EEPROM would be expecting to write data, aborting the write is probably better than writing data the processor knows nothing about.  Easy to do with bit-banging; harder to do (if even possible) on many hardware I2C implementations.

   Many hardware I2C implementations require that the processor decide, before reading each byte, whether or not it should be positively or negatively acknowledged.  In many cases, it would be more convenient to have a "read byte" routine which send a positive acknowledgment acknowledges the previous byte (if any), reads the next byte, and doesn't the acknowledgment until the next byte is needed; once no more data is needed, call an "end-read" routine to send a negative acknowledgment.  Such an approach is easy when bit-banging, but I know of no hardware I2C implementations that allow one to read a byte without having to know--in advance--whether it will be the last one.

The ease or difficulty of writing a bit-bang I2C master implementation is essentially independent of the number of devices on the bus.  I2C slave implementations are generally difficult or impossible without at least some level of hardware support, but big-banging an I2C master is easy.

Answer (score 0):

If your application processor has I2C hardware which can operate in master mode, you certainly can use it to communicate with slave devices.

Compared with bit-banged GPIO implementations, it can be faster in terms of development time to use the on-board hardware. Most likely there will be some libraries which will simplify mode setting and the general activity that the I2C master will need to perform (reads, writes, ACKs, NACKs, general call, serialization of bytes inand out, etc.)

However, if the I2C hardware is buggy, or the libraries don't give you the functionality you need, you may find it better to go with GPIO bit-banged I2C and avoid using the I2C hardware. The downside, of course, is having to write much more code.